# What is this JSON-like structure with 's:number' (s colon number) in front of a string called?

Tags: php, arrays, json

What is this **format** called that has similarities to JSON? It represents an PHP object, just like JSON would be able to do. However, clearly this is not JSON.

`O:36:\"Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\":2:{s:44:  .....    ;s:4:\"null\";}}`

`O:36` probably stands for Object and 36 properties (?)

`s:4` seems to stand for string and 4 characters.

---

What is this syntax / format called?

Comment: [PHP serialization format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format)

Comment: Though with the slashes, it looks like it's been run through the json_encode after the serialization